# Bootstrap Tabbable Nav Setting Tab-Section2 Height to Tab-Section1

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a tab nav with 2 tabs panes. Both tab contents are dynamic but first tab content has always more lines than the second tabs content. i dont want that the second tab content collapse when i click the second tab pane. I want to make the second tabs content height same as the first ones. How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: show us the page you're working on? I've used bootstrap and I don't know exactly what you mean

Answer (score 2):

You could override the CSS for `.tab-pane` and set the `height` attribute if you want all tabs to be the same height:

```
.tab-pane {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i have found the solution. After page load , tab1 is active so i just did var tab_height = $('.tab-content').css('height');
$('.tab-content').css('height',tab_height); So that fixes the height for tab2 content too.

Answer (score 0):

Did it as Serkan suggested using Jquery and in one line.
The unique selector is to limit .tab-pane selection

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Fix the height of the inner tabs
    $('#unique_selector .tab-pane').css('height', $('#unique_selector .tab-pane').css('height') );
});
```